# Error when building mongocxx driver on Windows

Tags: c++, mongodb, mongo-cxx-driver

I am trying to follow [this guide](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-cxx-driver/mongocxx-v3/installation/), and I am currently at step 3.

So after running,

```
curl -OL https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/archive/r3.0.1.tar.gz
tar -xzf r3.0.1.tar.gz
cd mongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.1/
```

I try to do similar commands as in the [Windows guide for mongoc](http://mongoc.org/libmongoc/current/installing.html#building-windows):

If I do just

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release" "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:/mongo-cxx-driver"
```

I get an error

```
CMake Error at cmake/FindLibBSON.cmake:37 (message):
  Don't know how to find libbson; please set LIBBSON_DIR to the prefix
  directory with which libbson was configured.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/bsoncxx/CMakeLists.txt:67 (find_package)
```

So here I have tried different things, like adding the paths to the libsson directory:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release" "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:/mongo-cxx-driver" "-DLIBBSON_DIR=C:/mongo-c-driver/lib/pkgconfig/" "-DLIBMONGOC_DIR=C:/mongo-c-driver/lib/pkgconfig/" "-DBOOST_ROOT=C:/local/boost_1_62_0/"
```

This actually works, but then when I try to build with

```
msbuild.exe ALL_BUILD.vcxproj
```

I get an error:

```
C:\Users\Erik\Documents\mongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.1\src\bsoncxx\array\view.cpp(21): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include
 file: 'bson.h': No such file or directory [C:\Users\Erik\Documents\mongocxx-driver-r3.0.1\src\bsoncxx\bsoncxx_static.v
cxproj]
```

This file, "bson.h" seems to reside in the direcroty

```
C:\mongo-c-driver\include\libbson-1.0
```

but I am not sure why it does not find the file or how I could make it do so.

Greatly appreciate any input on this.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed writeup - it made it much easier to spot the error. I have an answer below that I think will unblock you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not setting `LIBBSON_DIR` and `LIBMONGOC_DIR` correctly. They should, in your case, be both set to `C:\mongo-c-driver`. The build system will automatically add `include` and `lib` to that base path as needed. You might find reading the appveyor script informative:

- Note the `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` for libmongoc here: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/master/appveyor.yml#L25
- And then the setup of `LIBBSON_DIR` and `LIBMONGOC_DIR` here when invoking CMake for mongocxx: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/master/appveyor.yml#L31

Comment: most awesome. bounty is coming in 11 hours.

Comment: Thanks! Happy to help.

Comment: Links are broken.

Comment: @ShawnicHedgehog - Looks like the appveyor integration was removed, because I think the Windows builds were added to the evergreen configuration. Have a look here: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/master/.mci.yml#L48

Answer (score 0):

October, 18 2016

This issue happens to Mac OS X as well, and maybe to other Un*xes.

1. Use version 3.0.2 (at least). (The official guide mentions 3.0.1, but there is a [bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CXX-880) fixed in 3.0.2).

```
curl -OL https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/archive/r3.0.2.tar.gz
```

2. I didn't change to `build` directory, but to the root:

```
cd mongo-cxx-driver-r3.0.2
```

3. If the C mongo driver (and libbson) isn't at the default directory, tell it to the cmake command, as well as say we are featuring modern C++ (11, 14, ...). In my case: C mongo driver is on /opt/mongodbDriverCpp (the same place to put on C++ mongo driver).

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release 
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/mongodbDriverCpp 
-DLIBBSON_DIR=/opt/mongodbDriverCpp  
-DLIBMONGOC_DIR=/opt/mongodbDriverCpp 
-DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=14
```

4. Make and Install

```
make

make install
```

5. The command to compile the test from the official guide (change `/opt/mongodbDriverCpp` to your right directory):

```
c++ --std=c++11 test.cpp -o run.test 
-I/opt/mongodbDriverCpp/include/bsoncxx/v_noabi 
-I /opt/mongodbDriverCpp/include/mongocxx/v_noabi/ 
-L /opt/mongodbDriverCpp/lib 
-l mongocxx 
-l bsoncxx
```

6. Run (start the mongodb server first)

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/mongodbDriverCpp/lib

./run.test
```